# LAMP stack with AWS performance

Tags: mysql, php, amazon-web-services, lamp, high-load

I am planning to move my LAMP stack to AWS as the number of users increases. Current estimations suggest, that the Server has to handle roughly 100.000 users accessing the static landing page, out of which about 5.000 will use the internal pages (PHP and Database access). Can I use AWS to host my site and what should I pay attention to?

Comment: 100,000 users per *what*? Concurrent? Per day? Per month?

Comment: Or maybe per fortnight.

Comment: @mo_st Have you made progress getting to your high capacity hosted environment?  Where did you land?

Comment: I'm using AWS Elastic Beanstalk and everything is working out so far

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
for server workload tuning analysis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use AWS for a site with a scale from 1 request a day to 1 million hits per second and beyond.

You really need AWS education to use AWS effectively, including designing for cost savings. Off the top of my head things to pay attention to:

- Load balancing (ELB)
- Auto scaling (AWS auto scaling) with AMI images
- Cost control (you need to understand AWS)
- Log collection and analytics (CloudWatch)
- Database selection and load (RDS probably)